# Stop program with timer

Tags: c++, timer

I'm creating a logistic project in C++ where I have to compare the execution time of a solver that I created with an open source solver.

So, what I need is to stop the solver that I created if it will run longer than the open source solver.

The problem is that I didn't find anything about a timer that stops the actual executing program.

Someone can help me?

Comment: If you want to compare the runtime of the two, then clearly both need to run to completion... On the other hand, if you just want to run until the first one completes, you'll need to use multiple threads, and then "kill" whichever thread hasn't completed. It's a bit tricky. Are you sure you actually want to do that? Take into account that you also probably need to ensure you get the correct result.

Comment: C++11 or earlier? Otherwise, do you use boost? Otherwise, Windows or Linux (or OSX)?

Comment: Are you thinking you would run the solvers simultaneously on the same computer as part of the same program then?  Doesn't sound a fair test to me.  Implement one solution and benchmark, then the other and benchmark.  Maybe need more info about your problem...

Comment: @MatsPetersson: As I understand it, the execution time of the open-source solver is the reference for algorithm termination of the OPs own solver. So, what needs to run to completion in any case is the open-source solver. If the custom algo will have to run to completion can't otherwise be determined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just launch a future, that sleeps for a given time and then call std::exit.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information about what you are solving I would suggest running both in a series of benchmarks using multiple objectives to solve if possible since both might perform differently in different situations. Running both in rigorous benchmarks will help make sure your results are valid. Also even if your solver takes longer knowing that time difference will be able to help you optimize it.